# WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext from another class

Tags: vb.net

How to call WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext from another class and thread Probably stupid on my part but i've searched everywhere and can't understand.

It does work if I put the worker and code in the body of Form1.

Form1:

```
Public Shared UIContext As WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    UIContext = WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Current
    Dim StartClock As New SendtoUI
End Sub
Public Sub updatelable(incomingText As String)
    Label1.Text = incomingText
End Sub
```

Test Class :

```
Public Class SendtoUI
    Private lastUpdated As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Private backgroundTimer As System.Timers.Timer
    Public Sub New()
        backgroundTimer = New Timers.Timer(1000)
        AddHandler backgroundTimer.Elapsed, New System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(AddressOf backgroundTimer_Elapsed)
        backgroundTimer.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub backgroundTimer_Elapsed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
        lastUpdated = DateTime.Now

        Form1.UIContext.Post(Sub()
                                    Form1.updatelable(lastUpdated.ToLongTimeString())
                                End Sub, Nothing)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Based on above,

> Label1.Text = incomingText

The line does get executed but the Label isn't updated. Probably so simple but i'm stumped.

Thanks for any help!

-TD

OK, I figured it out thanks to Jimi, I'm updating with what I ended up with and hopefully it can help someone else!

Simple form1 as follows:

```
    Imports System.Threading

    Public Class Form1
        Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Dim TestTHreadUI As New ThreadedBackground(SynchronizationContext.Current, New SendOrPostCallback(AddressOf UpdateUI))
        End Sub
        Public Sub UpdateUI(incomingText As Object)
            Label1.Text = incomingText.ToString
        End Sub
    End Class
```

ThreadedBackground Class:

```
Imports System.Threading

    Public Class ThreadedBackground
        Private backgroundTimer As System.Timers.Timer
        Public Sub New(UIContext As SynchronizationContext, UpdateAddress As SendOrPostCallback)
            SyncContext = UIContext
            SyncCallback = UpdateAddress
            backgroundTimer = New Timers.Timer(1000)
            AddHandler backgroundTimer.Elapsed, New System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(AddressOf backgroundTimer_Elapsed)
            backgroundTimer.Start()
        End Sub

        'SynchronizationContext used for Posting
        Public Property SyncContext As System.Threading.SynchronizationContext
        'The Object Callback address to call
        Public Property SyncCallback As System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback

        Private Sub backgroundTimer_Elapsed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)

            'SyncContext.Post(SyncCallback, CType(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString, Object))   ' using passed in SendOrPostCallback(SyncCallback)
            SyncContext.Post(New SendOrPostCallback(Sub() Form1.UpdateUI(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString)), Nothing) ' Not using SendOrPostCallback(SyncCallback), Direct call to form1 Sub using lambda 
            'SyncContext.Post(New SendOrPostCallback(Sub() Form1.Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString), Nothing) ' Not using SendOrPostCallback(SyncCallback), Direct call to form1 Control using lambda 

        End Sub
    End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'ld consider avoiding a static reference to a specific Object (Form in this case) in your class.
A way is to add some  properties to your class that can hold that reference.

Your code can be edited as:

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

   Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

      Dim StartClock As New SendtoUI
      StartClock.SyncContext = System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Current
      StartClock.SyncCallback = New System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(AddressOf Me.updatelable)
   End Sub

   'Delegate signature
   'Public Delegate Sub SendOrPostCallback(state As Object)

   Public Sub updatelable(incomingText As Object)
      Label1.Text = incomingText.ToString
   End Sub
End Class
```

Your class with new Properties:

```
Public Class SendtoUI
   Private backgroundTimer As System.Timers.Timer
   Public Sub New()
      backgroundTimer = New Timers.Timer(1000)
      AddHandler backgroundTimer.Elapsed, New System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(AddressOf backgroundTimer_Elapsed)
      backgroundTimer.Start()
   End Sub

   'SynchronizationContext used for Posting
   Public Property SyncContext As System.Threading.SynchronizationContext
   'The Object Callback address to call
   Public Property SyncCallback As System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback

   Private Sub backgroundTimer_Elapsed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)

      SyncContext.Post(SyncCallback, CType(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString, Object))

   End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I'm going to mark this as answered! And thanks, I was going to ask more, but my original intent was to keep SendUI agnostic ... to be called from other forms and this does just that so Thanks, So I was stupid lol, However, no need to respond, but my original Form1.UIContext.Post(Sub() I've seen referenced in other places and thought it should work, can you explain why not? Thanks again ....

Comment: @TD_Home  Have you tried to set, in your project, Option Explicit: ON and  Option Strict: ON? If you do, the problem comes out immediately. You have  `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Current` which is assigned to a static variable defined as `Public Shared UIContext As WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @TD_Home  Right, but was it useful or not?

Comment: Indeed it was, I'm going to post an answer to others to show what points I've learned. I'm not sure why WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext is even available since it is the same as Threading.SynchronizationContext and VS2015 wants to simplify to that, either way, my actual problem was not with that but the SendOrPostCallback, and also, how to call direct with Lamda as in my update. In the end for what I was after, I did want to know how to pass the updateUI sub because I'll have more then one caller calling it. I don't have enough points to upvote your answer sorry ...

Comment: @TD_Home  This is a good reading about the SynchronizationContext class [Parallel Computing - It's All About the SynchronizationContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/magazine/gg598924.aspx). You don't need to upvote, just mark your question as answered if the answer solves a problem. So you let others know it's useful.